# How are letters between governments being transported and delivered?

Tags: government, international-relations

Recently, it became somewhat common for governments to publish letters, like the two examples given below. I just wonder: How are those letters between governments and/or international organizations being transported and delivered? How long does delivery of such a letter take?

I can not imagine that some official just sticks a stamp on the envelope and hand it to an "ordinary" postal service like the USPS or the Royal Mail.

**Examples:**

[image: Example Letter 1]
[image: Example Letter 2]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplomatic_bag

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Formally, the letters get sent through diplomatic channels. That is, someone is transporting the letter in a diplomatic bag to a relevant embassy who delivers it or to its recipient directly.

More practically, the letters also get sent digitally (read: email, press release, twitter, etc.) so that the recipients get the message immediately.

(In case the latter makes you wonder about security: if someone hacked e.g. Trump's Twitter account and "sent" a fake diplomatic letter, it would end up getting denied shortly after. The formal letter is the one that actually matters.)

Comment: There is also the combination of the letter being sent digitally to the embassy, which prints and delivers it.

Comment: I'd imagine countries that send a lot of diplomatic mail to each other also have digital signature systems that they can use to authenticate messages from each other.

Comment: What happens if someone carrying a diplomatic bag gets robbed?

Comment: @Sean: I would presume the bag's duplicable contents get re-sent.

Comment: Digital transmission to an embassy has the advantage of secure channels, including encryption, so the embassy knows the message is authentic. The decrypted and printed copy is hand delivered by an accredited diplomat, so the receiving country knows it is authentic.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Do you have proof of this procedure? If yes, maybe you can extend the answer by editing in your findings. Will the original be delivered later, or does the copy replace the original?

Comment: @dirdi The obvious, and very well documented, historical instance is the Japanese attempt during WWII to deliver to the US State Department a document that could be claimed to be a declaration of war just before the Pearl Harbor attack. Various problems, including slow decryption and typing in Washington, delayed delivery until after the attack. See, for example, [Japan Admits It Bungled Notice of War in '41](https://www.nytimes.com/1994/11/21/world/japan-admits-it-bungled-notice-of-war-in-41.html).

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan:  I think you're not stating it plainly enough, but the delay in delivery (In Torah! Torah! Torah!, which was quite accurate in it's detail of Pear Harbor attacks, this was the very last scene in the film... in real life the attack was mostly over before the delivery) was rather serious.  Both nations were signatories to the Geneva convention and the delay in declaration of war until after the attacks started was a violation of the laws of war.  The bombing was a war crime because of poor timing.

Comment: Also, I highly recomend a read of the British Declaration of war on Japan following the Pearl Harbor attacks.   Churchill dictated what is considered to be a very overly flowery and humble declaration of war by diplomatic crowds and when an aid asked him why he was being so nice to the Japanese, Churchill quipped, "When you must write a letter to tell a man you will kill him, it costs you nothing to be polite about it."

Comment: @hszmv I agree with your comments from the point of view of general interest in history, but I was only presenting it as a very well documented instance of the transmission method (electronic to embassy, paper hand delivered by diplomats to the host government).